# testing google IAP button

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I finished a game on the unity game engine and I have an in app purchase button, I tried to upload my .abb file to the play store it said that my API needs to be >= 29, I got back to unity and edited my minimum API and uploaded the file for the internal test to test my IAP button. but the problem is my testing device API is 28 !! I tried Android Studio emulator and it did not work since the emulators have x86 the cpu

how can I install the app from the store to test the IAP button??
and why does google forces the API 29+, that will make me lose many of my users!
how some games are still getting published and compatible with lower API? I installed a game that is published on Jan 5, 2021, on my API 28 device and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistaken the target API level with the minimum API level.

You can set the minimum API level to as low as you want.

You need to set the target API level to 29 or higher.

Comment: okay i found it, i will try to submit a new version to test, thanks

Comment: although the default target is Automaticaly the highest API.doesnt that means that it should be api 30?